# Help submitting a form

Tags: javascript

This was working but has suddenly stopped for some reason. I can't see what's wrong. Can someone tell me what I am doing wrong here? I'm using an onclick event in a span tag then calling this function.

Firefox reports: `Error: document.forms[0].submit is not a function`

```
  function submitlogin() {
    document.forms[0].submit()
  }
<form method="post" id="submit" action="something.asp">
 <span id="button" onclick="submitlogin()"></span>
</form>
```

---

This is what the form looks like

```
  <form method="post" id="myform" action="">
    <div>
      <input type="text" id="name" name="name" />
    </div>
    <div id="btn-container">
      <span id="button" onclick="submitlogin();"></span>
    </div>
  </form>
```

Comment: Do you even need to use javascript?

Comment: Well, I'm using a background image that has a button on it. I've had to use css to align the x and y coords of that button then use javascript to submit the form. Is there a better way?

Comment: you can apply the css style to the button instead of replacing it with a span. E.g. see https://app.portasigma.com/login.jsp where we nicely style a button

Comment: @Carles, thanks for the link. It will be very helpful, indeed. Always learning something new. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

document.forms[0] is searching for a `<form>` in your code, which you don't have. A quick fix could be

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  function submitlogin() {
    document.forms["myform"].submit();
  }
</script>

<form method="post" id="myform" action="something.asp">
 <span id="button" onclick="submitlogin()">hello</span>
</form>
```

Comment: I do have a form tag. It encompasses the span tag

Comment: Capt, From inside the function, I can alert the id. I get: `[object HTMLSpanElement]`. Not sure if this helps

Comment: This edit should work, sorry I had a typo before. Notice I changed the id of the form to "myform" rather than "submit". I get paranoid that some browsers will not run the code correctly if you use keywords like that.

Comment: I agree with you and was exactly why I changed it too. :)  Let me give your edit a try. brb

Comment: No Capt. I get this error: `Error: document.myform is undefined`

Comment: We both missed a semicolon in the javascript :)

Comment: Thanks Capt. I get the same thing even after including the semicolon. `document.myform is undefined`

Comment: Sorry, it has been a while. I stopped being lazy and typed it up, the edited code works for sure.

Comment: Thanks OK. :)  You're not going to believe this but I'm still getting `document.myform is undefined`. This is weird for sure.

Comment: I copied your example into a new form and it does appear to work. I guess I've got something else going on here, eh?

Comment: Where is it telling you it is undefined? Can you edit your first post and include a little more code if there is any that you think could be causing the error?

Comment: Capt, this is really strange because your example does in fact work but I cannot use it in my form. I'm trying to delete different things to see if there is some sort of a conflict going on. Absolutely, I will post more code if I can't get this working within 2 minutes.

Comment: OK, I think I found it but I'm such a noob with javascript that I'm not sure why. Within my form, I have two div tags. When I get rid of the uppermost div, it works. Maybe because I have a different id?

Comment: Sorry for the delay. I added an action to your form and it worked using my javascript from this post. Where is the image you are clicking? Is is css? The javascript doesn't trigger unless the content inside the span is clicked. Either load the image inside the span tags, or define a size for the box through css.